# Why people like Hoeffding's inequality more than CLT?

Tags: probability, machine-learning, information-theory

I am reading some paper in information theory and machine learning, and I found that many people like to use the Hoeffding's inequality rather than the CLT. I know the Lindeberg Feller CLT can also be applied on independent variables which have different variance, so why people don't use that?

Comment: It's an actual bound, rather than an asymptotic whose precise significance in the finite $n$ situation can be unclear (without quantitative refinements like the Berry-Esseen theorem). But of course CLT, the Berry-Esseen theorem, and some erf asymptotics can furnish similar results.

Comment: Thank you Ian. Do you mean the normal distribution does not have the close form of its CDF, so we cannot know its convergence rate with respect to $\epsilon$?

Comment: No, I mean that you know that $P(|\overline{X}-E[\overline{X}]|>t)$ behaves for large $n$ in a certain asymptotic way, but the CLT alone furnishes no actual bound. You need a quantitative improvement like the Berry-Esseen theorem to obtain a bound on such a $P$ from CLT. And even Berry-Esseen is often rather pessimistic for nice situations like bounded random variables.

Comment: So you mean we only know when $n$ is going to infinity, the distribution function will converge to normal distribution function, but we don't know the bound (something likes that), right? We can use the Markov's inequality, but it cannot be applied on variables which have different variances, is it correct? And Berry–Esseen theorem provides us a method to measure the bound.

Comment: Markov's or Chebyshev's inequality is staggeringly weak in practice (the price paid for generality). You want much better than that in situations like sums of independent variables. But you do know a bound in certain circumstances; as I mentioned the Berry-Esseen theorem bounds the maximum of $|F_n(x)-\Phi_n(x)|$ in terms of the third moment of the variables (assuming they're iid). It's not the only result of its kind, but it's prototypical.

Comment: Got it. Many thanks! Then it seems Hoeffding's inequality works very good in independent, different variances, but bounded variables.